# How to graph thickness per volume added?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

Say I have here a cube with side length $1$. If I wanted to double its volume, I would have to add a layer of material $0.16109$ units all around it. If I wanted to make that same cube have triple volume of the original, I would have to add a layer of $0.09469$ units thick of material on top of the first extra layer. I used these equations here:

$1=3(2x⋅1^2)+(2x)^3$ for the first layer,

$1=3(2x(1.32218^2)+(2x)^3$ for the second.

Now I want to graph volume to thickness of the added layer like $(1;0)$, $(2;0.16109)$, $(3;0.09469)$, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's unclear what you want to graph. Do you want to graph how much extra material you have to add layer by layer to increase the volume by whatever factor?

Comment: I tried to post a picture to make it clearer. Basically, $x$ is the volume, and $y$ is the needed thickness of a new layer of material to reach $x$ volume, going from $x-1$ to $x$ volume, not from $1$ to $x$ volume. Hence the $1.32218$ in the second equation, because $1.32218=1+2⋅0.16109$. The $1.32218$ in the second equation is the width of the cube that came before it.

Comment: You need an extra term with an $x^2$ in the RHS...

Comment: Adding the layer of 0.16109 all around the 1 volume cube results a  $(2*0.16109+1)^3 = 2.31$. Does not look as doubling.

Comment: I do not see how you derived the equations for doubling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take different variables:

- let $s$ be the sidelength of the cube
- and $2a$ the sidelength increase

(coefficient $2$ is explained by the fact we want to have a "$a$" increase on each side)

Let us express the condition under the form:

$$(s+2a)^3-s^3=1$$

which is equivalent to:

$$6s^2a+12sa^2+8a^3-1=0. \tag{1}$$

Let us consider (1) as a quadratic in variable $s$ and parameter $a$. Its positive root is:

$$s=\dfrac{1}{6a}(-6a^2+\sqrt{6a(1-2a^3)})$$

with the following representation:

[image]

**Remark:** coefficients $6, 12, 8$ in (1) are resp. the number of faces, edges, and vertices of the cube. The following figure shows the interesting interpretation between the terms of (1):

[image]

Comment: I have completely changed my answer.